# Prevent the risk when using decrement/increment postfix operator in C++?

Tags: c++, operators, decrement, postfix-operator

Recently I found the risk when using st like this:

```
int i = 10;
int sum = 0;
while ( i-- ){
      sum = sum + i;
```

It actually get sum = 9 + 8 + 7 + .. + 1. So it lacks 10 in total. But I prefer this way of coding, it's fast and professional. Is there any advice to prevent from the risk and still have concise code?

Comment: Use a for-loop. I fail to see what is particularly "professional" about this.

Comment: Doesn't really tell the compiler your intention either, missed opportunities...

Comment: `while( (sum += i--), i);` is more concise, works correctly, but would probably get you fired.

Comment: `sum = 55; /* sum(1..10) */` is more concise, works correctly, and will get you praised where I work.

Comment: @silentbang: I bet you'd just love APL. ;-P

Comment: Writing obscure or overly concise code is the opposite of writing clear, maintainable and professional code. Writing professional code is not about showing your colleagues how clever and concise you can write your statements.

Comment: @Pablo : is the comma same effect as the symbol "&&" ? When I try "while( sum += i-- , i)" without the bracket it loops forever with strange values of i. if had bracket, it is correct as you mentioned

Comment: @silentbang according to operator precedence rules, both forms should be equivalent, but I guess its easy for a compiler (specially older ones) to mess up the evaluation order. That's why its a good idea to specify precedence manually using the brackets. Although its a better idea to avoid such easy-to-confuse expressions. As to what it means: `A, B` means "evaluate expression A, discard the resulting value, then evaluate expression B and use its value for the whole expression"

Answer (score 5):

You have a counter, a stop-condition and a decrement operation, so use a `for` loop - it's a much better fit than `while`:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 10; i > 0; --i) {
    sum += i;
}
```

*"Professional"*, concise and risk-free :)

**Edit:** Or if you want to be *really* concise:

```
int sum = 55;
```

Answer (score 3):

At least for this specific type of series (sum from 1..N) you can just do `N*(N+1)/2`. 10*11/2 = 55.

Comment: You probably meant `N*(N+1)/2`. In your example, `(10*10+1)/2 = 50.5` which is certainly wrong ;)

Answer (score 1):

Postfix increment/decrement can be pretty nasty.  I recommend not using it.  Your example isn't even the worst of it.  It's behaving pretty well: you're actually getting sum = 9+8+7+...+1+0;  So you are going through the loop 10 times as one would think.

As mentioned in comment, use a for-loop.

```
int sum=0;
for (int i=10;i;--i) sum+=i;
```

The prefix operator is much less confusing, and in some cases, makes faster code.

Answer (score 0):

Use do-while instead of while.

Answer (score 0):

No idea what you mean by "risk" and "professional" way of coding, this code is just wrong.  If you want it to look "similar" to what you wrote

```
int i = 10;
int sum = i;
while ( i-- ){
      sum = sum + i;
```

or

```
int i = 10;
int sum = 0;
do {
    sum += i;
} while (--i);
```

Comment: The `do-while` construct will end up executing the loop body 11 times, won't it?  Hard to say what counts as 'risky' in OP's world, but it seems dangerous to me.

Comment: Should execute 10 times after the edit.  You can still count it as risky - nasty things if `i` is not positive, etc.  Hard to make the best call without a context.